# Can I prevent screen timeout on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, backlight

In the CE based Windows Mobile you could prevent the screen back-light from timing out using the [SetPowerRequirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms920689.aspx) and [ReleasePowerRequirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919803.aspx) API's like so:

```
IntPtr handle = SetPowerRequirement("BKL1:", PowerState.FULL, 1, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
// screen won't timeout while you do stuff in here
ReleasePowerREquirement(handle);
```

Is a similar thing possible on WP7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode` to stop the screen backlight timing out and stop the screen from locking.

You can also use `PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` to allow the application to keep running under a lock screen.

Here's some more detail on those two options:

### UserIdleDetectionMode

Disabling this will stop the screen from timing out and locking. As an example, I disable UserIdleDetectionMode while downloading a large file, so the app doesn't kill the download half-way.

When the download is completed, I re-enable UserIdleDetectionMode so the screen can timeout as usual.

### ApplicationIdleDetectionMode

**NB:** This is a one-time hit. You can disable it, but you cannot re-enable it.

If you disable ApplicationIdleDetectionMode, your app will continue to run when the screen locks. Your app will still die if the user starts a different app.

The certification requirements ask that you prompt the user the first time you disable  ApplicationIdleDetectionMode. E.g. "This app will continue to run under a locked screen, and may drain your battery. Are you ok with that?" If you don't your app will be rejected.

Comment: N.B. Certification requirements around using `ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` have changed (in v1.4 of the doc). You must now minimize power usage when running under a lock screen.